# Using a drive letter in a path to the PowerShell New-Item command

Tags: powershell

This creates a new directory as expected:

```
new-item "c:\newdir" -itemtype directory
```

This also works:

```
$arr = "one", "two"
$arr | new-item -name {$_} -itemtype directory
```

Resulting in two new folders: `c:\one` and `c:\two` (assuming current directory is c:).

This fails with the error "The given path's format is not supported."

```
$arr = "c:\one", "c:\two"
$arr | new-item -name {$_} -itemtype directory
```

How can I make this work with a drive letter in the path?

Comment: Note to future readers: `{$_}` _looks_ like it should be `${_}`, but it is - and is meant to be - a _script-block_ argument, that effectively binds each input object passed through the pipeline as-is to the specified parameter.
A - partially outdated - explanation of this approach can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/06/23/flexible-pipelining-with-scriptblock-parameters/); nowadays, the approach only works
with parameters that _are_ designed to take pipeline input _in principle_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the -name with -path for new-item to work correctly.

```
New-Item -Name "Name" -itemType directory -path "C:\"
```

You could create an array of hashtable entries instead with the path as one entry and the name as another entry. Or, if the path is always going to be the same just pass it in as another variable.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the OP's problem _as stated_. Presumably, it was accepted because it made the OP realize that you cannot pass _paths_ to `-Name` and instead must pass mere directory _names_ AND combine that with `-Path` set to the _shared parent path_ in which to create the directories with the specified _names_.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**:

- Preferably, pass the paths *array* directly to the (implied) `-Path` parameter:

  ```
  $arr = 'c:\one', 'c:\two'
  # Positional use of $arr implies -Path
  New-Item $arr -ItemType Directory
  ```
- Alternatively, via the pipeline and a *script-block parameter* value:

  ```
  $arr = 'c:\one', 'c:\two'
  $arr | New-Item -Path { $_ } -ItemType Directory
  ```
- With directory *names* and their shared parent path specified *separately*:

  ```
  $arr = 'one', 'two'
  $arr | New-Item -Name { $_ } -ItemType Directory -Path C:\
  ```

---

If you do not specify a parameter name, `New-Item` binds the 1st positional argument to the `-Path` parameter.

Therefore,

```
new-item "c:\newdir" -itemtype directory
```

is the same as:

```
new-item -Path "c:\newdir" -itemtype directory
```

`New-Item -?` will tell you that `-Path` accepts an *array* of strings:

```
New-Item [-Path] <String[]> ...
```

Therefore, you don't even need the pipeline and can just pass your *array* of paths *directly*:

```
New-Item 'c:\one', 'c:\two' -ItemType Directory
```

---

*Several* of `New-Item`'s parameters accept pipeline input, and the only one that accepts input *by value* (input object as-is) is `-Value`, which doesn't 
help here.

The remaining pipeline-binding parameters require binding *by property name matching the parameter name*.

<sup>To determine which parameters accept pipeline input, run `Get-Help -full New-Item` and search for instances of string  `Accept pipeline input?       True`. This approach works with all cmdlets.</sup>

Thus, in order to bind to parameter `-Path`, the input objects must have `.Path` properties:

```
$arr = [pscustomobject] @{ Path = 'c:\one' }, [pscustomobject] @{ Path = 'c:\two' }
$arr | New-Item -ItemType Directory
```

However, given that any pipeline-binding parameters can take *script blocks* as parameter values that are *evaluated for each input object*, this can be simplified to:

```
$arr = 'c:\one', 'c:\two'
$arr | New-Item -Path { $_ } -ItemType Directory
```

Automatic variable `$_` reflects the pipeline object at hand, which in this case are the input *strings* in turn.

<sup>A - partially outdated - explanation of this approach can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/06/23/flexible-pipelining-with-scriptblock-parameters/); nowadays, the approach works
solely with parameters that are designed to take pipeline input *in principle*.</sup>

The command at the top with `-Name { $_ }` and `-Path C:\` - specifying the *names* separately from the *shared parent path* - works analogously.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`-Name` accepts directory *names* only; only `-Path` accepts *paths*.

Trying to bind the input *paths* to `-Name` results in error message:

```
The given path's format is not supported.
```

because the input *paths* contain characters such as `:` and `\` that cannot be part of a directory / file *name*.

Answer (score 0):

When we do this:

```
new-item "c:\newdir" -itemtype directory
```

"C:\newdir" is automatically resolved to the Path parameter of New-Item because it's in position 1. That makes it work

When we do this:

```
$arr | new-item -name {$_} -itemtype directory
```

Each value of $arr is put through the pipeline by value, which resolves to the Value parameter of New-Item. 
Since it has a Value AND a Directory ItemType, it throws a fit.

The Help file for New-Item shows that Path is a string[]. This means you can just do this:

```
$arr = "c:\one", "c:\two"
new-item -Path $Arr -itemtype directory
```

And it will create directories for all the values in $Arr.